# Docker/virtualisation and HDFS

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs

The project I'm currently working on uses a small Hadoop cluster to iterate over about 300gb of data. This data is analyzed and it fills up a mongoDb that is used later on by our system.

Right now the Hadoop cluster is running on 4 physical machine (old Dell Precision t3500's). For testing this was a great setup as I could easily interact, install and test with the machines. But obviously this is less desired when the program releases. For this step the most desired outcome would be to virtualize Hadoop. Spread it out over a set of Docker containers that can run within a cluster.

When searching the internet it quickly became clear that Hadoop can run in a environment like that. Most search results speak about Yarn and the actual hadoop instances and how to start them. That is all great but I was wondering: what happens to HDFS.

In my current test setup HDFS contains 300gb of data that is stored in triple (to prevent data loss). When the system goes live this data set will grow with approximately 250mb each day. Uploading all of these files into HDFS takes a...while.

Now to get to my question:

How would HDFS act when docker starts or stops certain containers. Can it still guarantee that it will not loose any data. And would it not takes ages to re-sync a new node? Also it is very well possible that I'm looking at this from the wrong perspective. I've never done this before so if I'm going the wrong way, please let me know.

*ps: I'm sorry if this is a bit of a long/vague question. But like I said this is uncharted territory for me so I'm looking for something that can point me in the right direction, Google only got me sofar but limits its information to YARN and Hadoop self*